# Hiding unselected options in an interactive flowchart/tree diagram

Tags: javascript, css, interactive, flowchart

I am looking for help with some Javascript code that I am trying to adapt from another website, but I can't get it to do what I want it to do.

I want to do this entirely with CSS and javascript in HTML code. I am a complete javascript beginner.

In the HTML code below, you can click on a checkbox and it reveals the next level of options.

However, what I want to have happen is when, say, 'Option 1' is picked, then 'Option 2' and 'Option 3' are then hidden. At present, they remain in view, able to be clicked on.

And then when, say, Option 1.2 is picked, then the other two options of 'Option 1.1' and 'Option 1.3' are hidden.

In essence, I want the user to be able to navigate down a tree but only one single branch at a time, and after they make a choice, the unselected options in the same level disappear.

Of course, the reverse can be true in that if they clear an option at a higher level, then the full menu comes back into view at that level.

I've tried a multitude of different codings, but they either hide everything or make all checkboxes non-responsive! My lack of javascript syntax knowledge is showing here, but I think the solution involves turning the non-ticked boxes in the same level to the class of 'hide' whilst leaving the one that was ticked as ticked and on show with the class of 'active'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    ul,
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .box {
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      /* Safari 3.1+ */
      -moz-user-select: none;
      /* Firefox 2+ */
      -ms-user-select: none;
      /* IE 10+ */
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .box::before {
      content: "\2610";
      color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 6px;
    }
    
    .check-box::before {
      content: "\2611";
      color: dodgerblue;
    }
    
    .nested {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Interactive Decision Tree</h2>

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><span class="box">Option 1</span>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li><span class="box">Option 1.1</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.1.1</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.1.2</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.1.3</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="box">Option 1.2</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.2.1</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.2.2</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.2.3</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="box">Option 1.3</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.3.1</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.3.2</span></li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 1.3.3</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <li><span class="box">Option 2</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li><span class="box">Option 2.1</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.1.1</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.1.2</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.1.3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span class="box">Option 2.2</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.2.1</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.2.2</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.2.3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span class="box">Option 2.3</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.3.1</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.3.2</span></li>
              <li><span class="box">Option 2.3.3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <li><span class="box">Option 3</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li><span class="box">Option 3.1</span>
              <ul class="nested">
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.1.1</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.1.2</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.1.3</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 3.2</span>
              <ul class="nested">
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.2.1</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.2.2</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.2.3</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="box">Option 3.3</span>
              <ul class="nested">
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.3.1</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.3.2</span></li>
                <li><span class="box">Option 3.3.3</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>


  <script>
    var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
      toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
        this.classList.toggle("check-box");
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for additions that are needed to make it work as hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I coded a solution to my own question. I realised that the example I posted was insufficient in its capabilities to have checkboxes ticked and items shown whether you go up or down the choice list. It therefore needed a different approach, which is presented below. This works for me, plus I fully understand it as I wrote it all, adapting code from various other sources. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        ul,
        #myUL {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #myUL {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .box hide {
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            /* Safari 3.1+ */
            -moz-user-select: none;
            /* Firefox 2+ */
            -ms-user-select: none;
            /* IE 10+ */
            user-select: none;
        }

        .box::before {
            content: "\2610";
            color: black;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 6px;
        }

        .check-box::before {
            content: "\2611";
            color: dodgerblue;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .show {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Interactive Decision Tree</h2>
    <p id="O" class="box">Start</p>
    <p id="O1" class="box hide">Option O1</p>
    <p id="O11" class="box hide">Option O11</p>
    <p id="O111" class="box hide">Option O111</p>
    <p id="O112" class="box hide">Option O112</p>
    <p id="O113" class="box hide">Option O113</p>
    <p id="O12" class="box hide">Option O12</p>
    <p id="O121" class="box hide">Option O121</p>
    <p id="O122" class="box hide">Option O122</p>
    <p id="O123" class="box hide">Option O123</p>
    <p id="O13" class="box hide">Option O13</p>
    <p id="O131" class="box hide">Option O131</p>
    <p id="O132" class="box hide">Option O132</p>
    <p id="O133" class="box hide">Option O133</p>
    <p id="O2" class="box hide">Option O2</p>
    <p id="O21" class="box hide">Option O21</p>
    <p id="O211" class="box hide">Option O211</p>
    <p id="O212" class="box hide">Option O212</p>
    <p id="O213" class="box hide">Option O213</p>
    <p id="O22" class="box hide">Option O22</p>
    <p id="O221" class="box hide">Option O221</p>
    <p id="O222" class="box hide">Option O222</p>
    <p id="O223" class="box hide">Option O223</p>
    <p id="O23" class="box hide">Option O23</p>
    <p id="O231" class="box hide">Option O231</p>
    <p id="O232" class="box hide">Option O232</p>
    <p id="O233" class="box hide">Option O233</p>
    <p id="O3" class="box hide">Option O3</p>
    <p id="O31" class="box hide">Option O31</p>
    <p id="O311" class="box hide">Option O311</p>
    <p id="O312" class="box hide">Option O312</p>
    <p id="O313" class="box hide">Option O313</p>
    <p id="O32" class="box hide">Option O32</p>
    <p id="O321" class="box hide">Option O321</p>
    <p id="O322" class="box hide">Option O322</p>
    <p id="O323" class="box hide">Option O323</p>
    <p id="O33" class="box hide">Option O33</p>
    <p id="O331" class="box hide">Option O331</p>
    <p id="O332" class="box hide">Option O332</p>
    <p id="O333" class="box hide">Option O333</p>


    <script>
        function getElementsStartWithId(id) {
            var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
            var elements = [],
                child;
            for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
                child = children[i];
                if (child.id.substr(0, id.length) == id)
                    elements.push(child);
            };
            return elements;
        }

        function getNextLayerDown(id) {
            var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
            var elements = [],
                child;
            for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
                child = children[i];
                if (child.id.substring(0, child.id.length - 1) == id)
                    elements.push(child);
            };
            return elements;
        }

        function getAllPreviousLayers(id) {
            var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
            var elements = [],
                child;
            var newId = id
            do {
                for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
                    child = children[i];
                    if (child.id == newId)
                        elements.push(child);
                };
                var newId = newId.substring(0, newId.length - 1);
            }
            while (newId.length > 0);
            return elements;
        }

        function updateShowItems(itemId) {
            // hide all previous shown items
            for (i = 0; i < showItems.length; i++) {
                showItems[i].classList.remove("show");
                showItems[i].classList.remove("check-box");
            };
            var checkedItems = getAllPreviousLayers(itemId)
            // add check-box to all layers picked already
            for (i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
                checkedItems[i].classList.add("check-box");
            };
            // update show items list with latest click
            showItems = getAllPreviousLayers(itemId).concat(getNextLayerDown(itemId));
            // show all items now required
            for (i = 0; i < showItems.length; i++) {
                showItems[i].classList.add("show");
            };
        }


        // set each ID to be a trigger point
        var allItems = getElementsStartWithId("O");
        var showItems = getNextLayerDown("O");
        console.log(showItems);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
            allItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                updateShowItems(this.id);
            });
        };

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```